Uploading file with java google drive api hangs in aix
With the same code to upload file to google drive, linux and windows work well. but it does not work in aix.
It hangs in "update.execute();"
void upload(AbstractInputStreamContent content, String driveFile, boolean replaceFile) {
    // First try to see if the metadata for the file already exists.  If so,
    // update it.
    File file = findMatchingFile(driveFile);
    if (file != null) {  
        if (replaceFile) {
            try {
                // update content
                File newMetadata = new File();
                newMetadata.setName(file.getName());
                newMetadata.setParents(file.getParents());
                Drive.Files files = service.files();
                Update update = files.update(file.getId(), newMetadata, content);
                update.execute();

Can you give me some ideas on it?
Latest version of google-api-services-drive does not fix the issue.
Thank you.
